# All my objects are white when I build for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I recently started building a game for iOS using my iPhone 5s for testing.

However, recently I have decided to try my iPhone SE to see how it looks; all of the materials on all of the objects appear to be missing, but the color of the trails for the particle effects and the line renderers still have their color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a shader issue or a problem with the graphics API Unity is using. If you're not using the standard shader then make sure that you're shader is compatible with mobile devices. Also make sure that it's included in the project by creating a folder named *Resources* and moving your shader into that.

---

If you're using one of the standard shaders that comes with Unity then the issue is likely not a shader one but the Graphics API selected. It's likely using Metal which is causing that issue. Use OpenGL ES instead of Metal.

Disable Auto Graphics API then change iOS Graphics API to OpenGLES2 or OpenGLES3 in Unity's Player Settings.

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm! Another question though am I able to use Linear color space at all for Ios or only gamma?

Comment: I really don't know about that. You should try it. If it works then you can. If not then you can't